# Java collection program showing error - Stack is abstract, cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, collections, stack

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackDemo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Stack st = new Stack();
    }
}
```

While running this code on JCreator with JDK 1.6 an error is occured -

> Stack is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>           Stack st = new Stack();

Otherwise program runs successfully on online compilers like http://www.compileonline.com/

Please help.

Comment: Do you have some other abstract class with the name `Stack` in your classpath?

Comment: @RohitJai No, I don't have any other class named Stack.

Comment: @ShreyasA Does `java.util.Stack st = new java.util.Stack();` work?

Comment: @ShreyasA Try removing the import statement - `java.util.*`, and see if you get error on `Stack` saying cannot resolve symbol. If not, then certainly you have a different class in your classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do:

```
java.util.Stack st = new java.util.Stack();
```

You probably have an *abstract* class called `Stack` in your project.

Note that `Stack` is a raw type, don't forget to infer generic type arguments.

Comment: @ShreyasA See, you have another class with name `Stack`. Either imported from different library, or you created it.

Comment: @RohitJain yeah, got it!